# Getting props in a sub function when using a HOC

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make a HOC that handles some functionalities in react and i am creating my HOC this wat

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function withFormControl(WrappedComponent) {
  return props => {
    const onChangeField = e =>
      setFields({ ...fields, [e.target.id]: e.target.value });

    const [fields, setFields] = useState({});

    const submitForm = e => {
      console.log(fields);
      e.preventDefault();
    };

    return (
      <WrappedComponent
        onChangeField={onChangeField}
        submitForm={submitForm}
        fields={fields}
        {...props}
      />
    );
  };
}
```

And i am using it in my component like this:

```
    import React, { useState } from "react";
    import { Col, Form, FormGroup, Label, Input, Button } from "reactstrap";

    import { Typo, Ico, AuthLayout } from "../../../components";

    import "./Applicant.css";
    import FormInput from "../../../components/common/FormInput/FormInput";
    import withFormControl from "../../../hocs/WithFormControl";

    function Applicant(props) {
      console.log(props); // I get the props here 
      const subFunction = props => {
        console.log(props); // returns undefined
      }
    }
    export default withFormControl(Applicant);
```

I cant get the props in the inner function, any reason for this behavior?

Comment: what is subFunction? How do you use that? Btw that is invalid javascript in example.

Comment: am calling it a sub function, cause it's a function within the scope of another function,
why invalid?

Comment: Yes, but how are you using that? sure the props can be undefined when you are calling that subFunction without any parameters for example. Well 
const subFunction (props) => {
        console.log(props); // returns undefined
      }
you propably forget to assign that lambda?

Comment: Thanks pointing that out, but that doesnt seem to be the problem, i still get an undefined

Comment: ok i will repeat that question. can you please provide a code how do you call the function called subFunction? Btw i guess you really dont want to pass props as a function argument and shadow props from outer scope. You can just omit the props as param and access props from closure

Comment: yesss, i can get it from the closure, and i was calling the function as   const 
checkProps = (props) => {
    console.log(props);
  };
  checkProps(); //Here

Comment: well yeah.. do you sea the problem now? You are calling your lamda withou any arguments but that lambda declaration except one argument.. checkProps(props) could be also the solution but ehh..

Comment: Very smart, thanks alot for saving me the confusion

Comment: yeah the guy who wrote javascript was for sure pretty smart person ;) i will sum it up in answer.. feel free to gimme upvote when its done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that param of function called subFunction is shadowing variable from outer scope and then subFunction is called without any params.